# Pass a MethodGroup as part of a Lambda to execute on privately scoped instance

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have a class that is a wrapper for another that implements a certain interface.

It is not always appropriate to be able to substitute a `DatedNode` for Node.  Therefore `DatedNode` can't just implement `INode`.

However, I'd like to make a method available on `DatedNode` that allows you to call a method on the underlying `INode` object where it matches a given signature.

For example,.

```
DatedNode dn; //assume initialised
INode parent = dn.Do(n => n.GetParent);
```

Internally `DatedNode` would call `GetParent` on `_referencedNode` passing in `_date`.

Below is a super simple example of the classes involved.

```
public interface INode
{
    //assume lots of methods following this signature... Node MethodXXXX(DateTime date)
    INode GetParent(DateTime date);
}


public class Node : INode
{

    INode GetParent(DateTime date)
    {
        return null;
    }
}


public class DatedNode
{
    private INode _referencedNode;
    private DateTime _date;

    public INode Do(Func<??, INode> func)
    {
        return ???
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to apply `func` to `_referencedNode`?

Comment: I want to be able to pass a method which is called on `_referencedNode` which conforms to the signature `INode Methodxxxx(DateTime date)`

Comment: `Func<DateTime, INode>` is the lambda type. Or is `??` a type parameter? Then you want `public INode Do<T>(Func<T, INode> func)`. Or are you saying you need to restrict this to methods *of INode* whose names start with the prefix "Method"?

Comment: But what you really should do, I think, is use interfaces the way they were meant to be used: `var inode = someDatedNode.AsINode(); if (inode != null) { inode.SomeMethod(); }`. Or `if (someDatedNode.IsINode) { someDatedNode.AsINode().SomeMethod(); }`. The conventional way to call a method on an interface that might not be supported is to query the object for the interface, and check for null.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do the following `dn.Do(n => n.GetParent)` Internally `DatedNode` would call `GetParent` on `_referencedNode` passing in `_date`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes, I could create methods that wraps each equivalent `INode` method passing in the local instance `_date`.  I just thought there might be a way to do this without the need for the extra methods.

Comment: Wait, are you just saying you want a default argument on interface methods?

Comment: No, I could add the following to `DatedNode`:

`public INode GetParent()
{
   return _referencedNode.GetParent(_date);
}`

But if I have 30 methods on INode following that exact signature I wanted to know if there was a way to let the consumer of IDateNode chose to call any method on INode without me then having to add a new wrapper method each time.

The example in my question is contrived to make it simple.

Comment: Yeah, still getting my head around your requirements. Well, you could do something with reflection and `Expression<Func<Object>>`; is that what you had in mind with `dn.Do(n => n.GetParent)`? If it were me I'd make all the parameters `DateTime? date = null` in `INode`. Then I'd have a method on `DatedNode` which returns some concrete class that implements `INode` but with a default date. 30 methods is a drag, I agree. I'd probably generate those with a regex.